# itemMoved callback not working in ng-sortable library

Tags: javascript, ng-sortable

itemMoved callback is not working in ng-sortable library, whereas orderChanged Callback is working. Is there any configuration required for itemMoved Callback?

Answer (score 1):

The itemMoved callback only fires if an item is moved between two separate lists, not within the same list (like orderChanged).